# What folder can I put mp3 music for a xbox usb harddrive

Tags: xbox-360

What folder can I put mp3 files on a Xbox USB drive that has been formatted to be a hard drive? I formatted a micro USB drive with Xbox 360 and it formatted it into a Xbox hard drive. I was able to transfer a game save and profiles to it. But the folder architecture is weird. So which sub folder reads mp3?

Edit: Required information... it is a Xbox 360

Comment: Which xbox are we talking about? 360? One?

Comment: 360 sorry let me edit the question

Comment: AFAIK its simplest to put non-xbox files on a nonformatted drive, or outside the formatted partition. It will read the nonformatted partition like any other USB device, and use it in tandem with the formatted partition on the same drive.

Comment: I did do that. Unfortunely, I need to transfer it to my brothers harddrive. The other harddrive is mine. My little bro wanted my music. So transferring is important. I just need the correct location or methods to get it in the drive. Xplorer won't work. It won't even read it.

Comment: Hey Ignatius, I edited your question just to clear some formatting/spelling stuff up. Now, just for some clarity on this, you're just aiming to put MP3 files on this Xbox 360 drive, correct? And all you need to know is where specifically to put them?

Comment: Microsoft is using pretty weird paths (not a real one but an example) 53001830288820 > 53729472 > 0000001 > then the file is here. What path do I put mp3?

Comment: In the harddrive itself.

Comment: I formatted my micro sd and used a usb stick to transfer profiles. But I do not know the xbox path for music/video or how to treat mp4 / mp3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From sources [here](http://www.wikihow.com/Take-Music-From-Your-Computer-and-Put-It-on-Your-Xbox-360) and [here](http://www.gamespot.com/forums/xbox-association-1000003/transferring-music-to-my-360-via-flash-drive-26069059/), it would seem that it is impossible, if not ill-advised, to try and transfer music to your 360 hard drive. You can play music from a few different sources though, which are talked about in both sources:

1. Flash Drive

By putting the MP3 files on a flash drive, you can navigate to them with the 360 interface, and play them.

2. Rip a CD

Apparently, and this is news to me, you can rip files off of a disc and onto the 360. **What's interesting about this option is that perhaps, once the files are ripped off the disc, you could potentially look through the filesystem for where the files were placed. That would be a good bet on where to place MP3 files, though playing them back afterwards is an unknown.**

3. Stream through Windows

There is the option to stream music through Windows Media Player. I also seem to recall a Windows Media Center which would do largely the same thing, but it's been retired as far as I know.

Comment: I don't think its impossible. I just created some folders and was able to download a game save and transfer it. I just don't know the paths to put mp3 and mp4

Comment: Like a path on my sd card is 0000000000000000 > FFFE07DF > 00040000 > which is a location that holds a file called ContentCache.pkg I just need to know the location to put mp4 or mp3

Comment: But... ripping a CD.. would give me the location for mp4... I can do this from the xbox console yeah?

Comment: @Ignatius As the WikiHow guide states, yes.

Comment: Alright. It will produce a xbox specific file or a mp4?

Comment: @Ignatius Unfortunately I can't say for sure, I've never actually ripped a CD to a 360 before, so I don't know.